# HELP....How to delete extra DIV element from HTML Document?

Tags: html

I am developing a News application and for this i am using a web product for fetching News Headline. When I call a NewsHeadline, product sends a Html Code including News Headline.

```
<div class="mydiv">


<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('&lt;div style="display: none"&gt;');
</script><div style="display: none;">

<div>< a href="http:// www.abc.com.au/ news_manager/default.aspx ?z=41">Main News Item 6</a>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('&lt;/div&gt;');
</script></div>

<script src="http://www.abc.com/news_manager/ajaxzone.aspx?z=41&amp;pz=125&amp;h=1&amp;sort=startdate&amp;ord=desc&amp;xlaparsing=true" language="javascript"></script><div id="xlaANMzone_928960"><div class="" id="928960"><h5>
  <a href="http://www.mysite.com/article.asp?a=1144&amp;Z=41">
     test article from anil
  </a>
</h5>
</div>
[red]<div align="left"></div>[/red]
</div>

</div>
```

The Newsproduct is sending an extra div ie (`<div align="left"></div>`) on the lower end of above code. and this div is taking extra space in IE 6, and 7 only. its working fine in OPera,FF and Safari.

So what I need is to DELETE this extra div either on document ready or on load event. 
I used some scripts not worked for me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just like 4thpage already showed, I would use jQuery for this job as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[align=left]').remove();
});
```

This code will fire on the document.ready event and then search for any div-tag with the attribute `align=left` and will remove that element from the DOM.

Comment: I put like this in the <Head> tag.
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[align=left]').remove();
});
  
</script>

But it  didnot work on IE

Comment: did you add a reference to the jQuery library as well? Look at http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery for downloading jQuery.

Just add the reference to like

`<script src=jQuery-1.4.2.js language=javascript></script>`

You probably want to do this before your other script-tage.

Comment: @@nyx3x

Thanxx for Reply..

Yes I included Jquery library.. but No Solution Yet

Comment: what browser did you try that on? Could you post your current code here?

Comment: Tested on IE 7. Only this is creating problem of extra Div space.
<head>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script language= "javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[align=left]').remove();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
/// dynamically created divions here
</body>

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but you can check by

```
 var check = $("div").css('display');
        if (check == "none") {
           /// Doing action here
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply.....

Infact  I am newbie in JQuery. So better if you describe some more points...